# Tensorflow model serving not working when used inside a grpc call

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, grpc, tensorflow-serving, grpc-python

Have created a rpc service using grpc. when I try calling the tensor flow predict function inside a grpc call (predict) .I am getting a tensorflow related error and found out that tf.global_variables() becomes empty. Here is the code

```
class ModelServiceServicer(modelService_pb2_grpc.ModelServiceServicer):
"""Provides methods that implement functionality of route guide 
   server."""

def __init__(self, model_dir_path, metrics_enabled, metrics_service):
    self.metrics_enabled = metrics_enabled
    self.metrics_service = metrics_service
    self.serialized_model = TfContainer(model_dir_path)
    self.input = ["""#input"""]        
    **#this works**
    print(self.serialized_model.handle_predict(self.input))        
    print("intialized")
    print(tf.global_variables())


def predict(self, request, context):
    print("request is ")
    #print(request)
    print(context)
    start_time = datetime.now()
    print(self.input)
    print(self.serialized_model)
    try:
        **#this becomes empty**
        print(tf.global_variables())
        **#this does not work.**
        print(self.serialized_model.handle_predict(self.input))
    except:
        traceback.print_stack()
        print('------')
        traceback.print_exc()      **
    print(self.serialized_model.handle_predict(self.input))        
    print("intialized")
    print(tf.global_variables())
```

Help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The actual Servicer method calling is indeed happen in another thread, specifically with in the ThreadPool you provided when you initializing the server. According to the TensorFlow [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/global_variables) `tf.global_variables` seems not directly bound to threads, not like `tf.local_variables`. Can you provide more information regard to what is expected value of `tf.global_variables`? Or a minimal reproducible snippet is even better!